# Piping output from an output stream to an input stream

Tags: java, sockets, piping

My problem is piping input from one socket to another. Currently, I am using this code:

```
                    for(;;)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            output2.write(input1.read());
                        }
                        catch(Exception err)
                        {
                            err.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Even though this technically works, is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ByteStreams#copy(InputStream, OutputStream)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream)) from Google Guava:

```
try {
    ByteStreams.copy(input1, output2);
} catch (IOException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external libraries and without knowing any more than you have an OutputStream and an InputStream, you can use something like this.

```
byte[] buf = new byte[ 1024 ];
int read = 0;
while( ( read = in.read( buf ) ) != -1 ) {
    out.write( buf, 0, read );
}
```

This gives you the benefits of block moves, instead of single byte moves as in the code you posted.

This can be improved if we had more information on the types of IO streams you are using. You could look at [Java.NIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) which can provide much quicker block moves in the case of files or sockets.

Comment: This is exactly what he was trying to avoid?

Comment: Without knowing the types of streams you are dealing with, there isn't another way that provided by the standard library to copy one stream to another stream.

Comment: You are correct. I bet it's the internal implementation of ByteStreams anyways.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex It's due to the abstraction of InputStream and OutputStream. The data could come from anywhere and could go anywhere. Which is nice most of the time. If you have a specific case of moving files or transferring data to a socket. Then you can optimize with Java's NIO package, but the JVM can not tell the OS to do stream copies on all implementations of InputStream and OutputStream